# Netbeans update from 6.9 to 7.1: effect on project?

Tags: netbeans, java-6

I'm using Netbeans 6.9 on JDK 6.0.3.

I've an web application which is built on JDK 6.0.3 using Netbeans

If i upgrade JDK to recent version and netbeans to the latest version, does it affect on the already developed web application?

Comment: Did you use any of the special features of NetBeans to build your application? Which?

Answer (score 1):

No, in netbeans you may have multiple JDKs and build each project with the corresponding one. Check this at Tools-->Java Platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is just an IDE, switching to a new version will not affect your already written code neither the Java compiler.
Switching to Java 7 sometimes can give you problems... but usually not.